# Error - ArgumentException was unhandled by user code when adding to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, pdf

I'm trying to find all `.pdf` files in a directory and then save the paths in a text file. The directory where I'm searching for files contain a lot of subfolders and it contains more than 50,000 pdf file.

The code below work if I search a folder that has less then 40,000 pdf files. I have been able to create the dictionary and save it to a file with 38,199 paths.

I have tried using `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` and `Directory.GetFiles()` and both give me the same errors. I say errors because I have seen two different errors.

ERROR 1 (see pictures) points to `partsDictionary.Add(name, file);`

Any idea what could be wrong?

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createIndexedFileWithContentFromDirectory(@"C:\SomeFolder\");
    }

    private void createIndexedFileWithContentFromDirectory(string directory)
    {
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.pdf*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string file in files) {
            var name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            partsDictionary.Add(name, file);
        }

       // Write dictionary to a file 
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\SomeFoler\indexedFiles.txt", partsDictionary.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value).ToArray());

        MessageBox.Show("Indexing Complete");
    }
```

### ERROR 1:

[image]

### ERROR 2:

[image]

Comment: Please post your error messages as text, not as images. This saves bandwidth and the text can be indexed for searching.

Comment: The first error is pretty straightforward.  An item with the same key already exists in that dictionary.  Dictionary keys must be unique.

Comment: The first error is clear enough. You have two files with the same name in different folders. Now the key of the dictionary is the name of the file and this causes the duplicate key exception

Comment: And second exception tells you that while WPF was trying to construct your `MainWindow` - its constructor threw an exception (the first one, with duplicated key in dictionary). So fixing first exception will fix both.

Comment: Do you need the dictionary elsewhere or you can simply use the list returned by EnumerateFiles?

Comment: @Steve Actually no, dictionary `partsDictionary` can be contained inside `createIndexedFileWithContentFromDirectory()` method. I tried deleting it and using `files` instead but now I'm having issues when writing to the file. I was under the impression that `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` returns one path at a time not a collection.

Comment: Never mind, I looked at the documentation and it looks like it does return a collection. Do you see any performance issues if I use the dictionary is I have 
 in my code? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The problem is not in the performance when filling the dictionary but is in the fact that you have two files with the same name in different folders. I would use a simple list

Comment: Oooh, I see, make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of the duplicate key is caused by some file in the subfolders searched that have the same name. Adding the name for the first file is fine, but when you find the second file with the same name in a different folder you get the exception.

I don't know if you really need a dictionary for other works, but if you don't need it but you just want to write out a file then you can fix the method in this way:

```
private void createIndexedFileWithContentFromDirectory(string directory)
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.pdf*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\SomeFoler\indexedFiles.txt", 
         files.Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x) + "=" + x).ToArray());

    MessageBox.Show("Indexing Complete");
}
```